# error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Tags: updates, dpkg

When I am running sudo apt-get -f install, it shows dpkg: error processing. I've also ran `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27- 
3ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 362976 files and directories currently 
installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27- 
3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.de
```

`grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

`apt-get -f install`

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 362976 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Echo of `apt-cache policy libc-bin`

```
root@2wy:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# apt-cache policy libc-bin
libc-bin:
  Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu10
  Candidate: 2.27-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.23-0ubuntu10 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please show us the command and full output. And `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: @nobody updated!

Comment: I need from `sudo apt -f install`  please.

Comment: @nobody apart of it,updated!

Comment: The issues are occurring while unpacking the deb. Run `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb; sudo apt install -f`

Comment: I removed it, but when `sudo apt install -f` it happened again @Kulfy

Comment: something wrong with libc-bin `apt-cache policy libc-bin` please.

Comment: @nobody I added!

Answer (score 9):

The thing which worked for me is these two commands:

```
sudo fuser -kv /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

and then

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

The fuser command is a very smart unix utility used to find which process is using a file, a directory or a socket. It also gives information about the user owning the process and the type of access. The fuser tool displays the process id(PID) of every process using the specified files or file systems.

- `k` flag is for killing a process (`--kill`)
- `v` flag is for detailed and clear output (`--verbose`)

References:
[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-fuser-command#:%7E:text=The%20fuser%20command%20is%20a,specified%20files%20or%20file%20systems.)
[Techmint](https://www.tecmint.com/learn-how-to-use-fuser-command-with-examples-in-linux/)
[Similar Question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229886/866008)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have removed all files in `/usr/share/doc/libc6` and then `libc6` from `/usr/share/lintian/overrides/`.
Finally `sudo apt -f install` worked.

Answer (score 0):

First you can try `sudo apt upgrade libc-bin`

According to package search your Version is from xenial.

When the problem can not be solved this way try `sudo apt install --reinstall libc-bin=2.27-3ubuntu1`

No luck? `wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb` draw the package and use `dpkg -i libc-bin_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Comment: No hope! Thanks for helping me out during the time. I bought a new server!