# libc6 error, can't install anything

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I wanted to install `python-pip` so i ran `sudo apt install python-pip` and got this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcrypt20:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
 libgpg-error0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libgpg-error-l10n:i386
 libidn2-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 liblz4-1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 liblzma5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libunistring2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 18.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

it says `Try "apt --fix-broken install"` so I did that and got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
88 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2578 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 269716 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.30-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.30-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.30-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tryied also running `sudo apt-get install -f` didn't work

So what shall I do?
Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Please re-run commands after prepending `LC=C` (for example `LC=C sudo apt-get install -f`) and paste the output, so that we can see them in English.

Comment: ok made it, now it is in english

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok I have done

`sudo fuser -kv /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`

and

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

and now it works

Comment: You will be able to accept your own answer, maybe after a delay of a few days, and get your question marked as "Solved".